# Package management with go vendoring

Tags: go

How do you use go vendoring. It is written many places that 1.6 now include vendoring, but I can not find any documentation?

When use `go get`, I see no vendor folder?

I just need to be able to control packages like npm, apt etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.5 (with a flag) and 1.6 by default the go tools will look in the `vendor` folder for dependant packages before your `GOPATH`, for specifics see [the design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bz5-UB7g2uPBdOx-rw5t9MxJwkfpx90cqG9AFL0JAYo)

But the go tools do not include tooling to populate that folder for you.

There are many tools that try to handle it for you, for example [Godep](https://github.com/tools/godep), [gvt](https://github.com/FiloSottile/gvt) and others.

You still need to use `go get` to get the packages into your `GOPATH` first.

Comment: Could I then just manualy copy the forhindre.com/or other to the vendor folder?

Comment: Yes, you can, that is basically what the tools do for you. But if your package forhindre.com/foo depends on other packages you need to recursively copy them to the vendor folder too, or those depedancies won't get vendored.

Comment: The go repo's wiki has a nice page with a list of package management tools https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools